# How can I set system default figures to lining figures while keeping text figures as oldstyle figures?

Tags: fonts

I am using the `cfr-lm` package in (pdf)LaTeX to set document default figures to oldstyle figures. However, this package also sets the system numbers (eg. section numbers) to oldstyle figures. This can't be fixed with the `cfr-lm` commands `\lstyle`, `\plstyle`, and `\tlstyle`, since the section numbers are set by the processor. How can I switch the default figure style for these system figures to lining while keeping the oldstyle in the text?

Edit: here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}\rfoot{}
%\usepackage{sectsty} %%%This line and the next would ideally not be included
%\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} %%%
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=true}, sf={lining=true}]{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

123456789. As you can see, without changing the section font to sans serif, the section numbers are also being displayed in oldstyle figures.

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Edit 2 (My MWE edited to show the problem with the suggested fix):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}\rfoot{}
%\usepackage{sectsty} %%%This line and the next would ideally not be included
%\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} %%%
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=true}]{cfr-lm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textl{\arabic{section}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

As you can see, only the first number of the section number is changed.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the documented package options `rm={lining},sf={lining}`? And how do you setup titles? Are they in a different font, do you use a package?

Comment: @TeXnician well, I've tried all the package options, but only got the desired results when changing the section font to sans serif using `\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}`. However, I would like to use roman for my section font as well. The `rm` option changes all roman fonts including the section titles.

Comment: If you really want us to help you you have to give us the opportunity to do so. Hence it would be very kind if you could add a MWE to show us a minimal document especially with the important package you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`cfr-lm` does nothing to the section numbering.*** There is no such thing as 'system figures'. Section numbers and titles are set using the fonts specified by the class or package. By default, they use the document's default serif family. `cfr-lm` changes this font. If it did not, the text of your document would be the default. `cfr-lm` no more changes the font used for section numbers than it changes the font used for the second paragraph of the third section. That is, these may change if other code you load uses the default serif for them. But `cfr-lm` neither knows nor cares two hoots what code you are loading or not loading for customisations of this kind. It just configures the default fonts and loads `nfssext-cfr` to facilitate access to various non-NFSS font changes.

If you alter the style of numbers used for section numbering, I would alter the style for the section titles, too. It will look odd, otherwise, should you have figures in the section titles.

To do this, just adapt the customisation you give the `sectsty` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}\rfoot{}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\lstyle\upshape}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

As you can see, all the numbers of in the section number are changed.

0123456789

\end{document}
```

[image: lining numbers in section titles; hanging elsewhere]

Comment: Thanks! Now I realise how the `\sectsty` really works. @cfr

Comment: @VictorZ It is adding to the existing font, I think. So if you wanted `\mdseries` or whatever, just add it back in, too.

Answer (score 2):

The `sf` option you give sets the *sans-serif* font family, not the *system-font* as you called it.

In order to achieve your result you should renew the section command using `\textl`: a font command detailed in page 12 of the `cfr-lm` documentation, which ensures the lining figure is used.

The key line is:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textl{\arabic{section}}}
```

which makes the lining figures appear for the section numbers. AFAIK there's no way to do this automatically

Here a complete mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}\rfoot{}
%\usepackage{sectsty} %%%This line and the next would ideally not be included
%\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} %%%
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=true}]{cfr-lm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textl{\arabic{section}}}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}

123456789. As you can see, without changing the section font to sans serif, the section numbers are also being displayed in oldstyle figures.

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I provide a more general solution which does not care about how the section nr. is currently defined, and should work for *composite* section numbers, eg when the section number is composed by the chapter number also.

The result is the same as above. I opted to use the font switch `lstyle` instead of `\textl`, so that we do not have to surround with braces the arguments.

What I did is I "saved" a copy of the representation of the current way the section number is presented (`thesection`) and applied the font style to it

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}\rfoot{}
%\usepackage{sectsty} %%%This line and the next would ideally not be included
%\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} %%%
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=true}]{cfr-lm}
\let\oldthesection\thesection
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\lstyle\oldthesection}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}

123456789. As you can see, without changing the section font to sans serif, the section numbers are also being displayed in oldstyle figures.

\section{Second section}



\end{document}
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But what does the `arabic` in your change mean?

Comment: Also, the fix does not affect the second and third numbers of section numbers. I have edited the question to show this. @Moriambar

Comment: This will also affect cross-references etc., won't it?

Comment: @cfr I guess so, since it redefines the counter

Comment: @VictorZ if I get the chance I'l edit this in the evening. `arabic` transforms the counter into a number with arabic numerals (ie 1,2,3...) opposed to, say, roman numerals (i,ii,iii...)

Comment: @Moriambar Counter as in the section numbers?

Comment: @VictorZ yes the section number is internally contained in a "thing" which (La)TeX calls counter. Whenever you want its representation you could choose how to represent it. E.g. `\alph` gives the lowercase letter, `\roman` the roman numeral, and `\arabic` the arabic numeral.

Comment: @Moriambar I see! But why did the fix not work for the second and third numbers of the section?

Comment: @VictorZ by second and third number you mean something like `Section 123`? Those work fine for me. Otherwise it depends on how your section number is defined

Comment: @VictorZ if you like, please try my new, more general, solution

Comment: @Moriambar Thanks for the improved fix! I tried it and it works well. However, I think the fix proposed by cfr is more suited for my needs as it deals with defining the style of the entire section, which is good as numbers within the section title will also be changed.